# Making my subclass intercept messages

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an `NSPopUpButton` that I have subclassed that I plan to use in multiple locations within my program.  It's subclassed because it has special functionality to it.

Normally to receive actions events, you create a method in the controller class and then connect it with interface builder to handle the action.  For example if a user changed one of the options in the `NSPopUpButton` it would send a message to an interface builder action method such as below.

```
- (IBAction)sourcePopUpMenuChanged:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"sourcePopUpMenuChanged");
}
```

This is fine in most cases, but in my case I want to have it send the message to the subclass it's self and not the controller class.  I want to do this because I am setting a global variable behind the scenes to keep track of the index for the `popUpMenu`, since the popupmenu appears in many different windows in my application.

I'm aware that I could just create `IBAction` events for every window for this control and manually set the global variable everytime but this seems inefficient.

Is there a way that if ANY INSTANCES of my control receive an 'Action' Message, that I can run some kind of code, for example, like set a global variable for `gIndex = PopUpMenu Index Selected`.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: There should be no global variables in your project.

Comment: If there should be no global variables then what should there be? Also I'm working from a code base I don't have much control over, everything in the program is based from an old C program that I'm porting over to Cocoa.  It heavily relied it's logic upon global variables so I'm kind of stuck with it.  I'm open to other suggestions.  I've copied over it's global variables into a header file and gave the extern command to every single one so I could use them.

Comment: I see. So there you can not easily get rid of all the globals at once. My recommendation would be to encapsulate the globals in a class and access them from new code only through an instance of this class. Then you can gradually adapt your existing code to use that class as well until you can remove the global variable and instead really use the property of your object. (You should’t put all globals in the same class of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, you can override the method `sendAction:to:` on your `NSPopUpButton` subclass to do your stuff. Just don’t forget to call `super` so that the action message is forwarded to the regular receiver.

When a control wants to send the configured action it uses the `sendAction:to:` method which calls `sendAction:to:from:` on `NSApp` (the single `NSApplication` instance). This method follows the responder chain to find the final recipient of the action message.